# ¿Cómo mapear entidad débil?

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo dos entidades fuertes/dominantes y una débil (que une a las 2 fuertes), muestro la e-r de las tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo mapeado las tablas "usuario" y "contacto" que son las entidades dominantes, que muestro a continuación las clases:

Clase Usuario: lo básico

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idUsuario;  
@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;
@Column(name = "correo")
private String correo;
@Column (name = "contrasena")
private String contrasena;
@Column (name = "direccion")
private String direccion;
@Column (name = "imagen")
private String imagen;

public int getIdUsuario() {
    return idUsuario;
}

public void setIdUsuario(int idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public String getContrasena() {
    return contrasena;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}

public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}      
}
```

Clase Contacto: lo básico

```
@Entity
@Table (name="contacto")
public class Contacto implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idContacto;
@Column(name="nombre")
private String nombre;
@Column(name="correo")
private String correo;
@Column(name="direccion")
private String direccion;
@Column(name="imagen")
private String imagen;

public int getIdContacto() {
    return idContacto;
}

public void setIdContacto(int idContacto) {
    this.idContacto = idContacto;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
}

public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}              
}
```

Mi duda se presenta acá cuando tengo que mapear la tabla "usuario_asigna_contacto". Donde esta tabla contiene los PF id_usuario y PF id_contacto referentes de las tablas usuario y contacto, respectivamente. Yo ya he intentado hacer algo, pero me gustaría saber por uds (por experiencia) si está bien lo que hice o mal, o bien, si existe otra mejor forma.

Clase UsuarioAsignaContacto:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario_asigna_telefono")
public class UsuarioAsignaContacto implements Serializable {  
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_usuario")
private Usuario idUsuario;
@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_contacto")
private Contacto idContacto;

public Usuario getIdUsuario() {
    return idUsuario;
}

public void setIdUsuario(Usuario idUsuario) {
    this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
}

public Contacto getIdContacto() {
    return idContacto;
}

public void setIdContacto(Contacto idContacto) {
    this.idContacto = idContacto;
}
}
```

Tengo procedimientos almacenados para llenar las 3 tablas:

```
--PROCEDURE PARA INGRESAR DATOS A TABLA USUARIO
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE agregar_usuario (
v_nombre       usuario.nombre%TYPE,
v_correo       usuario.correo%TYPE,
v_contrasena   usuario.contrasena%TYPE,
v_direccion    usuario.direccion%TYPE,
v_imagen       usuario.imagen%TYPE
) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO usuario VALUES (
    NULL,
    v_nombre,
    v_correo,
    v_contrasena,
    v_direccion,
    v_imagen
);

COMMIT;
dbms_output.put_line('Usuario registrado correctamente');
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error al ingresar usuario');
    ROLLBACK;
END;
/

--PROCEDURE PARAINGRESAR DATOS A TABLA CONTACTOS Y A TABLA 
 USUARIO_ASIGNA_CONTACTO PARA LAS RELACIONES

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE agregar_contacto (
v_nombre               contacto.nombre%TYPE,
v_telefono             telefono.numero%TYPE,
v_correo               contacto.correo%TYPE,
v_direccion            contacto.direccion%TYPE,
v_imagen               contacto.imagen%TYPE,
v_correo_usuario       usuario.correo%TYPE,
v_contrasena_usuario   usuario.contrasena%TYPE
) AS
v_id_usuario    usuario.id_usuario%TYPE;
v_id_contacto   contacto.id_contacto%TYPE;
BEGIN
--AGREGAR CONTACTO
INSERT INTO contacto VALUES (
    NULL,
    v_nombre,
    v_correo,
    v_direccion,
    v_imagen
);

--OBTENER ID_USUARIO

SELECT
    usu.id_usuario
INTO v_id_usuario
FROM
    usuario usu
WHERE
    usu.correo = v_correo_usuario
    AND usu.contrasena = v_contrasena_usuario;

--OBTENER ID_CONTACTO RECIEN CREADO

v_id_contacto := seq_id_contacto.currval; 

--AGREGAR EN TABLA USUARIO_ASIGNA_CONTACTO PARA LAS RELACIONES
INSERT INTO usuario_asigna_contacto VALUES (
    v_id_usuario,
    v_id_contacto
);

--AGREGAR TELEFONO POR MEDIO DEL PROCEDURE AGREGAR_TELEFONO_CONTACTO

agregar_telefono_contacto(v_telefono, v_id_contacto);
COMMIT;
dbms_output.put_line('Contacto registrado correctamente');
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error datos no encontrados');
    ROLLBACK;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error al agregar contacto');
    ROLLBACK;
END;
/
---- PROCEDURE AGREGAR_TELEFONO_CONTACTO AGREGAR A TABLA TELEFONO Y 
TABLA CONTACTO_ASIGNA_TELEFONO PARA LAS RELACIONES ----

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE agregar_telefono_contacto (
v_numero        telefono.numero%TYPE,
v_id_contacto   contacto.id_contacto%TYPE
) AS
v_id_telefono telefono.id_telefono%TYPE;
BEGIN
--AGREGAR TELEFONO
INSERT INTO telefono VALUES (
    NULL,
    v_numero
);

--OBTENER ID_TELEFONO

v_id_telefono := seq_id_telefono.currval;

--AGREGAR EN TABLA CONTACTO_ASIGNA_TELEFONO
INSERT INTO contacto_asigna_telefono VALUES (
    v_id_telefono,
    v_id_contacto
);

COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error datos no encontrados');
    ROLLBACK;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error al ingresar telefono');
    ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A falta de más detalles, voy a suponer dos posibles escenarios:

1. La tabla que establece la relación entre las otras dos tablas tendrá algún campo extra, como por ejemplo una descripción del tipo de relación (por ejemplo si es un familiar, un colega, un amigo...).
2. La tabla que establece la relación entre las otras dos no tiene más campos que las claves primarias.

Si estamos en el primer escenario, entonces lo que has implementado es correcto, con una salvedad: los atributos de la tabla `UsuarioAsignaContacto` deberían llamarse usuario y contacto, y no idUsuario e idContacto, puesto que sus valores serán las entidades relacionadas, no sus identificadores.

Si estamos en el segundo escenario, la entidad `UsuarioAsignaContacto` es innecesaria y puedes eliminarla, creando lo siguiente:

Entidad Usuario,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idUsuario;  
    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name = "correo")
    private String correo;
    @Column (name = "contrasena")
    private String contrasena;
    @Column (name = "direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @Column (name = "imagen")
    private String imagen;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "usuario_asigna_contacto", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_contacto") }
    )
    private Set<Contacto> contactos = new HashSet<>();


    // getters y setters

}
```

Entidad Contacto:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="contacto")
public class Contacto implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idContacto;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;
    @Column(name="correo")
    private String correo;
    @Column(name="direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @Column(name="imagen")
    private String imagen;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "contactos")
    private Set<Usuario> usuarios = new HashSet<>();

    // getters y setters

}
```

Comment: Estamos en el segundo escenario, pero podrías explicarme un poco el funcionamiento de todo ésto ya que tengo procedimientos almacenados en oracle 11g xe para llenar las tablas, he actualizado mi pregunta añadiendo los procedimientos.Como al crear contactos, los asigno a un determinado usuario.

Comment: Viéndolo ahora con más detalle, no necesito la clase UsuarioAsignaContacto ya que a nivel de BD lleno esta tabla con los procedimientos almacenados y borro con el Delete Cascade en las referencias.