# Cómo mapear una entidad débil en Access y MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Para implementación Java encontré una pregunta similar: [¿Cómo mapear entidad débil?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/338745/c%c3%b3mo-mapear-entidad-d%c3%a9bil)

En el caso de mapearlo en Access, cómo sería el mapeo de una entidad débil? Y si lo exporto a OCBD para MySQL, qué cambios habría que hacer?

Muchas gracias. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Entidad" es un concepto del **modelo entidad-relación**, que describe las relaciones entre datos a alto nivel.

A la hora de diseñar la base de datos, traduces el modelo entidad-relación a un **modelo relacional**. En este modelo, las relaciones 1-1 o 1-N pasan a ser normalmente Foreign Keys, y las relaciones N-N tablas con foreign keys.

Así que lo que tienes es sencillamente una tabla con las foreign keys que correspondan.

La pregunta que enlazas hacer referencia a cómo se describe/enlaza a dicha tabla usando JPA, que es un framework ORM de Java y que mapea los objetos a tablas. No tiene mucho que ver con lo que tú preguntas (Java es un lenguaje de programación, MySQL y Access son bases de datos).

Comment: Entendido, lo tendré muy en cuenta para mis proyectos. Muchas gracias. @SJuan76