# Mapeo Entidad Débil Java persistente y Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

**Editado (2/10/20):** Para parte en inglés, aquí la pregunta en cuestión: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520556/how-to-map-a-weak-entity-in-spring-boot-and-java-persistence

---

**Editado (30/9/20):** La tabla en MySQL está de esta manera:

[image: Tabla ubicaciones_plantas]

Pregunta parecida en StackOverflow: [¿Cómo mapear entidad débil?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/338745/c%C3%B3mo-mapear-entidad-d%C3%A9bil)

---

Tengo una clase Java llamada UbicacionPlanta, de la cual es una entidad débil de Departamento.

La estructura entity es la siguiente:

```
@Entity(name = "ubicaciones_plantas")
@Table
public class UbicacionPlanta implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "iddepartamento", referencedColumnName = "iddepartamento", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Departamento departamento;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idubicacion")
    private Long idubicacion;

    @Column(name = "abreviacion_ubicacion")
    private String abreviacion_ubicacion;

    @Column(name = "descripcion_ubicacion")
    private String descripcion_ubicacion;

    public Departamento getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }
//Getters and Setters

}
```

En el IDE salta un error del tipo: [image: el Id Departamento No puede ser entidad persistente]

En cuanto al DTO, está desarrollado de la siguiente forma:

```
public class MUbicacionPlanta {

    private String departamentoId;

    private Long idubicacion;

    private String abreviacion_ubicacion;

    private String descripcion_ubicacion;

    public MUbicacionPlanta(UbicacionPlanta ubicacionPlanta) {
        this.departamentoId = ubicacionPlanta.getDepartamento().getIddepartamentos();
        this.idubicacion = ubicacionPlanta.getIdubicacion();
        this.abreviacion_ubicacion = ubicacionPlanta.getAbreviacion_ubicacion();
        this.descripcion_ubicacion = ubicacionPlanta.getDescripcion_ubicacion();
    }
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Cómo tendría que mejorarlo para que se integren iddepartamento e idubicación?

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: El error que tienes es porque a la entidad `Departamento` que es parte de la relación no debe de llevar la anotación `@Id`, para darte consejos de mejora debes colocar la entidad Departamento para verificar que las relaciones son correctas, luego exponer las entidades en el servicio REST no es recomendable, tienes que tener en cuenta que a la hora de generar el JSON te generara un error `Infinite recursion` porque las entidades tiene una relación recursiva y hay que anotar las realaciones con @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference para evitar el error.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Entiendo. Aún así, si quitas el Id a Departamento, cómo hay que enterarse de forman parte de la PK Departamento y Ubicación tanto en persistencia como en Hibernate?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta si puedes explicarte mejor, segun entiendo quieres una tabla intermedia entre UbicacionPlanta  y Departamento si es asi tienes que utilizar la relacion ManyToMany para ambas entidades y de esa forma hibernate creara la tabla intermedia. La anotacion `@Id` se debe de quitar a la realcion `Departamento` que esta en la clase la clase `UbicacionPlanta`.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Para mejor comprensión, si lo necesitas: Cómo mapear una relación 1 a N en JPA? Todas las entidades débiles se asocian a esto. iddepartamento se mantiene como maestra e idubicacion es la que varía de una forma consecutiva. No hay tablas intermedias N a M.

Comment: @RobertoEMoran Otro ejemplo claro de entidad débil es Factura con LineaFactura, también 1 a N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución adecuada mediante esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760730/how-to-mapping-an-onetomany-relation-with-weak-entity-in-hibernate

Entonces, Departamento se muestra mapeada de esta forma:

```
@Entity(name = "departamentos")
@Table
public class Departamento implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "iddepartamentos")
    private String iddepartamentos;

    @Column(name = "nombre_departamento")
    private String nombre_departamento;

    @JoinColumn(name = "sede_departamento", referencedColumnName = "sede_departamento", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Sede sede;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="departamentos")
    private Set<UbicacionPlanta> ubicacionPlantas;
    
    //Constructor, getters and setters

}
```

Y UbicacionPlanta se implementa de esta otra:

```
@Entity(name = "ubicaciones_plantas")
@Table
public class UbicacionPlanta implements Serializable {


    @JoinColumn(name = "iddepartamento", referencedColumnName = "iddepartamento", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
    private Departamento departamento;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idubicacion")
    private Long idubicacion;

    @Column(name = "abreviacion_ubicacion")
    private String abreviacion_ubicacion;

    @Column(name = "descripcion_ubicacion")
    private String descripcion_ubicacion;

    //Constructor, getters and setters
}
```