# Manejo de relaciones many to many con spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

Estoy haciendo api rest para un proyecto personal, actualmente tengo un problema con las relaciones many to many.
Tengo la siguiente relacion en la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la api quiero obtener un json con los datos de la tabla recetas incluyendo la tabla tipo.
Lo que tengo:

```java
// entity
// clase KitchenEntity que es la que corresponde a la tabla recetas
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "recetas",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<TypeEntity> types;

// clase TypeEntity que es la que corresponde a la tabla tipo
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<KitchenEntity> recetas;

// repository
public interface KitchenRepository extends JpaRepository<KitchenEntity, Serializable> {
}

public interface TypeRepository extends JpaRepository<TypeEntity, Serializable> {
}
```

**-- MODIFICACION --**
Modifique las clases repository y entity, ahora están así:

```java
// Clase KitchenEntity
// type
@JoinTable(
    name = "recetas_tipo",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_recetas", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_tipo", nullable = false)
    )
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<TypeEntity> types = new HashSet<>();

// Clase TypeEntity
// kitchen
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "types")
private Set<KitchenEntity> kitchens = new HashSet<>();
```

Las clases repository cambie Serializable por Integer

**-- MODIFICACION --**

Para que no se haga muy larga la pregunta elimino el mensaje de error y en lo dejo en un readme.md del proyecto que dejo a continuación
https://github.com/Pillado84/tus-recetas-favoritas.git.

Hay que situarse en la rama spring_v0.0.1, donde realizo el backend de cero cambiando de php a spring boot.

Comment: Quizá esto te aclare: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/338745/c%c3%b3mo-mapear-entidad-d%c3%a9bil/

Comment: @Pablo Lozano ya tengo probado como comenta en el enlace pero me sigue dando un error igualmente, deje una modificación de como lo tengo ahora después de volver a ponerlo como lo tenia antes